# How to transmit an Android Object to NetBean Java Project over a Socket?

Tags: java, android, sockets, object, netbeans

Im student, and i'm learning Android.
I have a project Android and a project Netbean.

This is model in Android Studio

```
public class Request implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private User user;
private String cmd;
private boolean isLogin;
private String mess;

public Request() {
}

public Request(User user, String cmd, boolean isLogin, String mess) {
    this.user = user;
    this.cmd = cmd;
    this.isLogin = isLogin;
    this.mess = mess;
}

public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}

public String getCmd() {
    return cmd;
}

public void setCmd(String cmd) {
    this.cmd = cmd;
}

public boolean isIsLogin() {
    return isLogin;
}

public void setIsLogin(boolean isLogin) {
    this.isLogin = isLogin;
}

public String getMess() {
    return mess;
}

public void setMess(String mess) {
    this.mess = mess;
}
```

}

This is model in Netbean project:

```
public class Request implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private User user;
private String cmd;
private boolean isLogin;
private String mess;

public Request() {
}

public Request(User user, String cmd, boolean isLogin, String mess) {
    this.user = user;
    this.cmd = cmd;
    this.isLogin = isLogin;
    this.mess = mess;
}

public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}

public String getCmd() {
    return cmd;
}

public void setCmd(String cmd) {
    this.cmd = cmd;
}

public boolean isIsLogin() {
    return isLogin;
}

public void setIsLogin(boolean isLogin) {
    this.isLogin = isLogin;
}

public String getMess() {
    return mess;
}

public void setMess(String mess) {
    this.mess = mess;
}
```

}

I proceeded to transfer object from android project to netbean project over socket connection.
Although the transmitted object has the same properties and is implemented Serializable, but on the Netbean I get the error message "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.kimericko.timbannhau.Model.Request".

This is err:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.kimericko.timbannhau.Model.Request
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:628)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1620)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1521)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1781)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
at Controller.MyServer.Listening(MyServer.java:67)
at Controller.MainController.main(MainController.java:15)
```

What am I having problems? Why can not cast object from Android project to Netbean project? What do I do to fix it?
Thank you very much

Comment: Unless the "Netbean project" is running on the same device as is your Android app, I would not expect `Serializable` to work reliably. Android and Linux/macOS/Windows are completely separate operating systems, with completely separate runtime environments. Use a platform-neutral data format: CSV, XML, JSON, protobuf, etc.

Comment: The code will execute if the android project is added as a project dependency to netbean java project. It won' t execute if both are in different places(IDE). Because netbeans couldn't find the classes which are in Android project. If you want that to be executed place the android project as dependency to netbean java project. But that is a bad practice. Use some platform independent data formats.

Comment: Do I have to convert my object to JSON? Is there any other way?